# past perfect tense with when

Tags: past-perfect, when

> "He had left the house when we arrived."
>   I feel it is most certainly wrong, but I figured it's safer to ask the community here. To me it feels like it should be "He had already left the house when we arrived," or "He had already left the house by the time we arrived." Am I wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Both of the alternatives you offer are grammatically correct and idiomatic, but the first supplies additional meaning to what was an already grammatically acceptable sentence.

***Already*** simply adds emphasis to the fact that he had gone, hinting that the speaker or their interlocutor would have expected him still to be there.

***By the time*** is simply an alternative to *when*.

Comment: Tim got to the airport at 6:30 pm. I called Tim at 6:50 pm. "Tim got to the airport when I called him." Would this also follow to be correct usage of when? If so do you have any sources that I might be able to check concerning this usage?

Comment: It is not entirely correct. You could say either *Tim was at the airport when I called him*, or *Tim was already at the airport when I called him*, or *Tim had reached the airport when I called him*. But if you are going to use *got* you need the pluperfect *Tim had got to the airport when I called him*.

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad. It should be "Tim had got to the airport when I called him." Do you have any references for this use of when and past perfect? It would be a great help.

Comment: Swan's Practical English, pg 425, says that the use of the past perfect is especially common with when. (when has several meanings, so we often have to show the exact time relations by the verb form.) e.g., When I had opened the windows, I sat down and had a cup of tea.

The time between the first clause and the second clause doesn't feel right. Unfortunately Swan's examples are sparse and are all resultives.